# Unhandled rejection(Typeerror):recipes.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EPSs.png)
this is the error am getting after running the app
what could be the problem when am rendering out this component in my parent component but after running it shows that map is not a function

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
`import "./Meals.css";`
import Axios from "axios";
import RecipeCard from "./RecipeCard";
function Meals() {
const APP__KEY = "6d6112cdc44e4e44acb74c969b3624fd";
const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const getdata = async () => {
        const result = await Axios.get(
            `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/716429/information?apiKey=${APP__KEY}&includeNutrition=true.`
        );
        console.log(result.data);
        setRecipes({
            data: result.data,
        });
    };
    getdata();
}, []);
return (
    <div className="meals">
        {recipes.map((recipe) => (
            <RecipeCard recipe={recipe} />
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

}

export default Meals;

Comment: Can you please show the result of `console.log(result.data)`?

Comment: uncaught Typeerror: recipes.map is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I think in setRecipies function you are passing an object just pass array result.data assuming result.data is an array. you are passing `{data:[]}`. that is why you are getting object `{data:[Array of data]}` instead of array.

correct way is `setRecipies(result.data)`

Comment: i get the {recipes:array} and this error Meals.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: recipes.map is not a function ,

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with `recipes` as with array,  you shouldn't set it as object:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getdata = async () => {
        const result = await Axios.get(
            `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/716429/information?apiKey=${APP__KEY}&includeNutrition=true.`
        );
        console.log(result.data);
        setRecipes(result.data); // set it as array, not an object
    };
    getdata();
}, []);
```